# Having trouble understanding a notation in negligible functions in cryptography with omega (ω)

Tags: notation, cryptography

The following is the definition of negligible functions I was given:

> Definition 2.1: $\nu$ is negligible if for every constant $c \ge 0$ there exists an integer $k_c$ such that $\nu(k) < k^{−c}$ $\;\;\forall k\ge k_c$.
>
> Another way to think of it is $\nu(k) = k^{−\omega(1)}$

I understand the definition of a negligible function but I can't find anything explaining the last line.

I am tasked with proving that  $2^{−\omega(\log n)}$ is a negligible function in an assignment, but what does the omega function mean?

Comment: I believe it's referring to a type of big-O notation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations

Comment: So what does the function 2^−ω(logn) mean?

Comment: $f(x)=\omega(g(x))$ is used in the context of computer science and asymptotic analysis to describe the relationship between the functions when $x$ is very large. It means that $f(x)$ asymptotically dominates $g(x)$. A more thorough explanation can be found on the Wikipedia page. Roughly speaking, it means that $f(x)$ can be made arbitrarily larger than $g(x)$, if we choose a big enough $x$. So if I'm right in how I read your equation, we could rearrange it to $-\frac{\ln(\nu(k))}{k}=\omega(1)$ so it would mean that $-\frac{\ln(\nu(k))}{k}$ asymptotically dominates $1$.

Comment: I understand that. So do you think that the question in the assignment is the same as proving that 2 ^ (-log n) is negligible?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure since this isn't my area of expertise. But I think if $f(n)=2^{-\omega(\log n)}$, then $-\frac{\ln f(n)}{\ln 2}=\omega(\log n)$. So you have that $\forall c>0 \,\exists n_0 \forall n>n_0. \left|-\frac{\ln f(n)}{\ln 2}\right|>c\left|\log n\right|$ by the definition of $\omega$. Also, I'd made a typo in my last comment; $k$ should be $\ln k$.